# Date split - algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a few date ranges which have to be split so that there would no overlapping sets. In the below table, record 0 has to be split to two as (0-1/01/2014-1/11/2014), (0-1/12/2014-1/12/2014) to differentiate that first range is range not overlapping with any other ranges and and second range is overlapping record# 1 range.

```
Table1
Record#    Start Date    End date
      0     1/05/2014     1/12/2014
      1     1/12/2014     1/23/2014
      2     1/14/2014     1/16/2014

Result Table need to be like this...

Table2
Record    StartDate    EndDate
     0     1/05/2014    1/11/2014
     0     1/12/2014    1/12/2014
     1     1/12/2014    1/12/2014
     1     1/13/2014    1/13/2014
     1     1/14/2014    1/16/2014
     2     1/14/2014    1/16/2014
     1     1/17/2014    1/23/2014
```

I have followed the approach below, but it didn't give me the desired results.

```
Prepare a list:

(1/05/2014, 1/12/2014, 1/14/2014, 1/16/2014, 1/23/2014)

Prepare interval list:

(1/05/2014, 1/11/2014), (1/12/2014, 1/13/2014), (1/14/2014, 1/15/2014),
(1/16/2014, 1/23/2014)
```

Comment: please edit your question and add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Need to see your code to help you :P

Comment: It is still unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JoD.I am trying splits the dates as shown above from table 1 to table 2

Comment: In order for us to help you, you need to give us two things via your question's [edit button](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31486324/edit): **first** - a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **second** - the desired results.

Comment: @JonnyHenly: I have deletd few records.. In above example, I  am trying to get results in table 2 from table 1. Hope it is clear now...

Comment: *"When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers **if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.**"* - [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This means, please edit your question and add your code so that we can reproduce your problem and solve it.

Comment: My method has has almost..150 lines...please let me know if you want me to copy all of it...